# CiviCRM CSS outside of CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, css, resource-urls

We've got some CiviCRM status messages displayed outside of CiviCRM (Drupal pages), but they come as a default browser JS alerts, not as a fancy CiviCRM-styled status messages. We've    **$manager->addCoreResources();** included via  hook_page_build(&$page); guess it's not enough though.

There is a documentation at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Resource+Reference    which says:

*If you are working outside of CiviCRM core or extensions (such as a Wordpress plugin), you can still use the Resource Manager but will need to construct the urls yourself*

with `addScriptFile, addScriptUrl, addStyleFile and addStyleUrl` methods available; the question is, which exactly CSS files contains fancy pop-ups formatting?

Also, it's a bit unclear, how exactly **css** should be loaded? Normally, it should use addStyleFile / addStyleUrl, but an example given at documentation page states:
CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->add**ScriptUrl**('http://example.com/**bar.css**' (mean, use addScript to load CSS Style file) which is a bit confusing..

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong question was asked; fancy CiviCRM stuff works almost, if properly called via CiviCRM own jQuery methods; pretty strange  **CRM.alert** in Chrome pops up a default JS alert() message though, so it might be better to use  **CRM.status** with appropriate parameters

This page helps a lot: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Notifications+and+Confirmations

*Additional reading:*

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Javascript+Reference
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Resource+Reference#ResourceReference-Javascript
- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Ajax+Pages+and+Forms#AjaxPagesandForms-CRM.refreshParent